# Changing top margin for second page only? \vspace inserts extra whitespace

Tags: spacing, formatting, margins

I am trying to format a LaTex template for pandoc output from .md to pdf. The document is for lengthy university papers requiring very specific layout. The majority of the paper has 1 in margins all around, with the exception of the Title Page and Primary Headings (which require 2 in top margins).

`\newgeometry` works for the Title Page because it is a standalone page, but it creates a new page when used with `\begingroup \newgeometry \section{Primary Heading} \endgroup` which is unacceptable.

I thought I could solve the problem using \vspace*{}, but it appears to insert extra whitespace which causes too much top margin (see pictures). How can I create exactly two inches of top margin before a `\section{Primary Heading}` appearing at the top of a page that is not the first page of the document?

**EDIT 1/17**
I succeed in getting chapters to work as expected instead of sections. Using titlesec along with titlespacing, I am able to add 1in above the chapter headings (which should combine with the 1in margin to = 2 in), but the output is more than 1in. Could I use something like \vspace to subtract the extra whitespace that is added? How could I calculate how much extra whitespace is added?

[image: Default behavior]
[image: \vspace*{0in} adds extra whitespace]
[image: \vspace*{1in} adds too much margin]

Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

% Package Imports
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{setspace} 
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

%% Section Formatting (Requires titlesec)
    %%% Primary Heading (H1)
        \titleformat{\chapter}
        {\center\normalfont\MakeUppercase}{}{0pt}{}
        \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1in}{0pt}
    %%% First-Level Sub (H2)
        \titleformat{\section}
        {\center\normalfont\MakeUppercase}{}{0pt}{}
        \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2em}{0pt}
    %%% Second-Level Sub (H3)
        \titleformat{\subsection}
        {\center\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
        \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{2em}{0pt}

% Page Formatting & Layout
    \raggedright %% Left Justify
    \doublespacing %% Line Spacing (Requires setspace)
    \geometry{margin=1in} %% Margins (Requires geometry)
    \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in} %% Fixes Paragraph Indentation
    %\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} %% No counters for section headings

\begin{document}

% Title Page
    \begin{titlepage} 
    \centering
    \newgeometry{left=1in,right=1in,top=2in,bottom=1in}
    \begin{singlespace}
    \uppercase{
    [Institution]\par
    \vspace{2in}
    [Paper Title]\par
    \vspace{2in}
    Submitted to [Professor]\par
    In partial fulfillment of\par
    [Course]\par
    \vspace{2in}
    by\par
    [Name]\par
    [Date]\par}
    \end{singlespace}
    \restoregeometry
    \end{titlepage}

% Body
    \chapter*{Primary Heading}\label{primary-heading}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section*{First-Level Sub}\label{first-level-sub}
    \lipsum[2]
    \subsection*{Second-Level Sub}\label{second-level-sub}
    \lipsum[3]
    \chapter*{References}\label{references}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Can you reduce your code to the minimum? For example, if you can reproduce the problem without a custom font setup, take the custom fonts out. Fonts are especially bad because they mean that only people who have those fonts can compile your code to reproduce the problem. Is the title page relevant? What about `polyglossia`? Also, it is easier for people if you combine the files so they can copy-paste a single code block.

Comment: Thank you. I will update the original post with minimal code. I didn't want to take anything out in case I took out something that was causing the problem. I'll update the post soon.

Comment: Thank you @cfr, I have clarified the question, added pictures, and a MWE.

Comment: Why aren't you using chapters which automatically start new pages, rather than sections?

Comment: The LaTex is automatically generated by pandoc from a markdown file. In the file #Primary Heading turns into \section{Primary Heading}\label{primary-heading}. I am pretty sure using chapters instead of sections would still not solve my problem though, correct?

Comment: Does the primary heading always start a new page? Or do you have to have a solution that test if the heading is the first line of a page, an then increase the space?

Comment: Chapters wouldn't solve all of the problem, but they are certainly a more natural choice here. For example, by default you get a new page with a dropped heading. The amount you drop by might need tweaking, but the basic structure would be there.

Comment: I am not opposed to using chapters. I dug into the pandoc documentation and it appears I can cause 1st level headings to code as chapters with the --chapters switch. I will post a new MWE using chapters later today.

Comment: @Sveinung, to clarify, primary headings are essentially chapter headings. Each time a primary heading is present, a new page needs to be started and the two inch top margin applied for that page only. I am going to switch to using \chapter instead of \section now that I know how to produce it with pandoc (see above comments by myself and @cfr).

Comment: @cfr I tried using the --chapters switch and outputting chapters instead of sections, but it created more issues (creates a blank page between title page and the primary heading and doesn't like not being numbered) and didn't solve the spacing issue. I would like to see if we can solve it using the code I have above with \section as the primary heading.

Comment: `openany` passed to your class will prevent it leaving a blank page before the chapter. But if you are going to print one-sided, `oneside` would be better (and will do the same thing). Your best bet, I think is to use `titleps` to set up a different page style for the first page of chapters (or sections - whichever). `titleps` is designed to work well with `titlesec`. You may do it with sections, but it may be more work. `titlesec` has a level `top`, as well as `chapter`, but I am not sure if it will know sections are the top level in a `book`.

Comment: @cfr, I succeed in getting chapters to work as expected instead of sections. Using titlesec along with titlespacing, I am able to add 1in above the chapter headings (which should combine with the 1in margin to = 2 in), but the output is more than 1in. Could I use something like \vspace to subtract the extra whitespace that is added? How could I calculate how much extra whitespace is added?